# Tumblr .permalink-page custom CSS don't scale content

Tags: html, css, tumblr, permalinks

I have added some custom CSS to my Tumblr Theme to make permalink pages wider (for static pages I've added) however this makes all the individual post permalink-pages wide and scales the images larger than 100%. Is there a way to tell it not to scale the content larger than 100% so that it does not become pixelated, using only CSS? I don't want to edit the actual HTML theme. Here is the added CSS code:

```
.permalink-page {
max-width: 80%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: auto;
font-size: 15px;
color: black;
```

}

Here is an example page I don't want stretch to full width: [Regular post](http://de-fine-art.com/post/117515818663/crossconnectmag-illustrations-by-eunjung-shin)
And here is an example of a page I want to be full width: [Static Page](http://de-fine-art.com/artevents)

Thank you!

Comment: Static pages on Tumblr adhere to the rules in {text} posts block, you could do it by editing the theme to customize each specific post type permalink page and then play around with the {text} block. It would be hard to do it solely using CSS though, since all post types will follow the default permalink page CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, I see two ways of solving it:

- If it is just a problem of pixelated images, you can edit your theme and increase image resolution on permalink pages:

{block:Photo} ... {block:PermalinkPage} ... **{PhotoURL-HighRes}**... {/block:PermalinkPage}

- If you need to change the css on static pages, create a custom theme for them (you can copy your main tumblr theme to here and just adapt the css):

[image: Create a specific theme for the static pages]